# How do I get radio value from the previous page after a using backward button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, onload

I was creating a form like this :

if select b, the textbox is disabled, but after this page there is a comfirmation page, and when you use backward button to switch back, the textbox is turned on again, so is there any method in js that can check the radio selection and alter the result before the after is loaded ?

Comment: And what is the code you did so for for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi why dont you store your flag values in html5 storage objects such as sessionStorage/localStorage, visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate flags temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your flags and then change the status of textbox depending on the flag

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('flag')=='1')
{
document.getElementById("textbox").disabled = true;
}
```

add above check in your onload function.

while redirecting to next page use

```
sessionStorage.setItem('flag',1);
```

to set flag